# Let X = $\{\emptyset,\{2\}, \{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\},1\}$. Then Which of the following are correct

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let X = $\{\emptyset,\{2\}, \{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\},1\}$. Then Which of the following are correct

1) $2\in X$

2) $|X|=6$

3) $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\subseteq P(X)$

4) $\{1,\emptyset\} \subseteq X$

**My attempt:**

```
(1) not true

(2) not true since |X|=5

(3) power set contain every set hence (3) is right

(4) not true

is this right? Please tell me if  I am wrong.
```

Comment: 4 seems correct to me.

Comment: @Flowsnake..can you explain me where i did wrong

Comment: $\{1,\emptyset\}$ is a subset of $X$.

Comment: @Flowsnake: $\{1,\emptyset\}$ not in X

Comment: $1$ and $\emptyset$ are both elements of $X$. So $\{1,\emptyset\}$ is a subset of $X$.

Comment: 3,4 both are correct, 1,2 are not correct

Comment: @Vikram...it mean (1) and (2) are not correct?

Comment: Those are subset symbols.  Not members of symbols. $\emptyset \subset X$.  So is $\{\emptyset\} $. so $\emptyset \in P (X) $ and $\{\emptyset\}\in P (X) $.  So $\{\emptyset\{\emptyset\}\} \subset P (X) $.  In 4) $1\in X $ and $\emptyset \in X $ so $ \{1,\{\emptyset\}\}\subset X $.  An interesting thing about 3) that set is a subset of both X and P (x).

Comment: Power set does not contain *every set*, but every *subset*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First (3): $A$ being a subset of $P(X)$ ($A\subseteq P(X)$), means that every element of $A$ is a subset of $X$. So in this case we should check if $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ are subsets of $X$. Wel surely $\emptyset $ is, so what about $\{\emptyset\}$. Well, $$x\in\{\emptyset\}\implies x=\emptyset\in X.$$ 
So, $\emptyset $ and $\{\emptyset\}$ are both subsets of $X$, i.e. elements of $P(X)$. Thus: $\big\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\big\}\subseteq P(X)$.

Now (4): $$x\in \{1,\emptyset\}\implies \big( x=1\in X \vee x=\emptyset\in X\big)\implies x\in X.$$ Thus $\{1,\emptyset\}\subseteq X$.

You were right about (1) and (2); they are both wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I agree (2) is false, but I would give reason $|X| \le 5$.  Perhaps some of the elements listed in $X$ are equal to each other, say $1 = \{\emptyset\}$.  To claim $|X| = 5$ we would have to disprove all such possible equations.  But of course we do not need to do all that work to answer (2).